# how many record we can insert into posts table in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

```
wp_insert_post($array);
```

How many record we can insert into posts table in wordpress and how many record we insert in woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter as many records as your database can hold. How much that is, is really up to your host and the amount of MySQL storage they provision per account.

Answer (score 0):

There are sites with more than 10000 posts using this function all the time and everything working fine. And its all depended On database which you using. If you find any problem try running a cleanup in your database to see if things get better.. .